# Create a python 'list' in C++

Tags: c++, python-2.7

I am trying to create a python `list` in C++, but I cannot seem to get the class from the `__builtin__`-module.

```
PyObject* o_builtin = PyImport_ImportModule("__builtin__");
PyObject* o_list = PyDict_GetItemString(o_builtin, "list");

if (o_list == nullptr) {
    cout << "could not find list in __builtin__" << endl;
}
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I should have used `PyObject* list = PyList_New(0);`